# Pipelining exercise

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture

We run the above code in a 4-stage IN-ORDER pipeline with F, D, X, W stages, where X takes 4 pipelined cycles for ADD and takes 6 pipelined cycles for MUL. Assume NO forwarding (bypassing), i.e., we need to stall on every data dependency. How many cycles will the code take to execute?.

The code and my answer is attached in the following picture. I think I should use excel because it looks more organized.

The answers are 27,28,29,30. I got 27. Is that right?. what do you get?[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should be 28 cycles takes to execute. Add use 4 pipeline cycle, Mul use 6 pipeline cycle. there are 4 ADD instruction and 2 MUL instruction. which, 4*4 + 2*6 = 28 cycles